# Admin vs users pages. Best way to set up? ASP.NET C# Membership Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a set of unauthorized pages that anyone can access (mainly the register page). Once a user is registered with personal info and group info, I want them to be admin, they then can access the authorized pages. On the authorized pages, I have a add member page, which creates a new user and that user inherits the admins group info. These people will be regular users and I don't want them to access the add member page and other select pages.

So whats the best way to set this up? I have an extra table that saves some extra user info for everyone, would I include some type of true/false admin column? ASP.NET configuration? What else?

I have my auth and un-auth pages set up with asp.net config with each set of pages in a different directory.

I'm using membership services, MS SQL, ASP.NET, etc

Comment: is this WebForms or MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like [`Role Management`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.aspx) should be a good solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to implement this would be to create a role via Membership Services for site Administrators.

You could then easily decorate your Admin only Controller Actions with:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign the users a role[user] while creating account...

use this this code to restrict non administrative users.

```
If User.IsInRole("Administrator") Then

Else


End If
```

Comment: you should edit your post and use the Code Sample button {} to format your code sample